# How to enable preview in child view, where child view takes a function as a parameter from the parent?

Tags: swiftui

```
struct ParentView: View {
    var KMOD: Double = 0.0425

    func calculateSetAI(reps: Int) -> Double {
        return 1 / ((Double(reps) * KMOD) - KMOD + 1)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ChildView(calculateSetAI: calculateSetAI)
    }
}
```

```
struct ChildView: View {
    // some state variables

    var calculateSetAI: (Int) -> Double
    
    // a newFunction() that calls calculateSetAI
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Output of newFunction: \(newFunction)")
    }
}
```

Attempt 1 ERROR: Missing argument for parameter

```
struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChildView()
    }
}
```

Attempt 2 ERROR: Cannot convert value of type '(Swift.Int) -> Swift.Double' to expected argument type '(Swift.Int) -> Swift.Double'

```
struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    var KMOD: Double = 0.0425
    func calculateSetAI(reps: Int) -> Double {
        return 1 / ((Double(reps) * KMOD) - KMOD + 1)
    }
    static var previews: some View {
        ChildView(calculateSetAI: calculateSetAI)
    }
}
```

Attempt 3 warning (and then crashes preview): Cast from '(RICalcView_Previews) -> (Int) -> Double' to unrelated type '(Int) -> Double' always fails

```
struct RICalcView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    var KMOD: Double = 0.0425
    func calculateSetAI(reps: Int) -> Double {
        return 1 / ((Double(reps) * KMOD) - KMOD + 1)
    }
    static var previews: some View {
        RICalcView(calculateSetAI: calculateSetAI as! (Int) -> Double)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `previews` property of a `PreviewProvider` is **`static`**.  That means it doesn't have a (hidden) `self` parameter.

In attempts 2 and 3, you declared `calculateSetAI` as an instance method, meaning it has to be called on an **instance** of `RICalcView_Previews`, which would be passed to it as the (hidden) `self` parameter. But there is no `self` value available in the context where you're mentioning it.

One solution is to add `static` to the declaration of `calculateSetAI` in attempt 2. You'll also need to add `static` to `KMOD`:

```
struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var KMOD: Double { 0.0425 }
    static func calculateSetAI(reps: Int) -> Double {
        return 1 / ((Double(reps) * KMOD) - KMOD + 1)
    }
    static var previews: some View {
        ChildView(calculateSetAI: calculateSetAI)
    }
}
```

Or you could just use an inline closure:

```
struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var KMOD: Double = 0.0425

    static var previews: some View {
        ChildView {
            return 1 / ((Double(reps) * KMOD) - KMOD + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could create an instance of `ParentView` and use its `calculateSetAI` method:

```
struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let parent = ParentView()
        ChildView(calculateSetAI: parent.calculateSetAI)
    }
}
```

Comment: brilliant!  great answer that didn't just solve the issue, but learned a lot from it, cheers